# Reading names with special characters using R

Tags: r, excel

I've an excel (xlsx) table and in the column "PLAYERS" European players have an asterisk in their names and South Americans don't. Something like this

```
  PLAYERS
   Neymar
   *Bale*
    Messi
*Ronaldo*
*Benzema*
*Iniesta*
  DiMaria
```

Is there any way I can use R (or excel itself) to split this dataset into one with Europeans (with asterisk) and another one with South Americans? Of course, the data set contains other columns like "SALARY", "SCORED GOALS", "OFFSITE", "AGE" etc. etc. etc.

Thanks,
Diego.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if there's an "*" in the players name and in a new column write "European" or "South American" and, if you want, you could then split the data frame into a list with two data.frames, one with Europeans and the other with South Americans:

```
df <- data.frame(PLAYERS = c("Neymar", "*Ronaldo*", "Messi"), SALARY = 5:7)
df
#    PLAYERS SALARY
#1    Neymar      5
#2 *Ronaldo*      6
#3     Messi      7

# check if there's a * in the PLAYERS column
df$Location <- ifelse(grepl("\\*", df$PLAYERS), "European", "South American")
df
#    PLAYERS SALARY       Location
#1    Neymar      5 South American
#2 *Ronaldo*      6       European
#3     Messi      7 South American

#split the data based on location:
dflist <- split(df, df$Location)

dflist
#$European
#    PLAYERS SALARY Location
#2 *Ronaldo*      6 European
#
#$`South American`
#  PLAYERS SALARY       Location
#1  Neymar      5 South American
#3   Messi      7 South American
```

Now you can access each list element (which is a data.frame) by typing

```
dflist[["European"]]  # or "South American" instead
#    PLAYERS SALARY Location
#2 *Ronaldo*      6 European
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Your suggestion was clean, fast and easy to implement :)

Comment: @DiegoMenezes, welcome, you can select the answer you like best and click the check mark next to it to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can split this specific column and name the resulting list with `split` and `setNames`

```
> dat <- structure(list(PLAYERS = structure(c(6L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 3L), 
                 .Label = c("*Bale*", "*Benzema*", "DiMaria", "*Iniesta*",   
                            "Messi", "Neymar", "*Ronaldo*"), class = "factor")),
                 .Names = "PLAYERS", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-7L))

> setNames(split(dat, grepl("[*]", dat$PLAYERS)), nm = c("Euro", "SoAm"))
#$Euro
#   PLAYERS
# 1  Neymar
# 3   Messi
# 7 DiMaria
#
# $SoAm
#     PLAYERS
# 2    *Bale*
# 4 *Ronaldo*
# 5 *Benzema*
# 6 *Iniesta*
```

Comment: Nice answer! Since I'm not a regex expert I wonder, does it make a difference here whether you use `"[*]"` or `"\\*"`? +1

Comment: @beginneR, it's a bit safer (and cleaner) for escaping metacharacters. `*` can get dangerous. This [R Text Processing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing) link is really good.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll have a look at that! I already wondered what might be a good way to learn more about regex - now I have somewhere to start.

Comment: Great Richard, your approach worked just fine. Thanxxx.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable from your source data with `PLAYERS` for ROWS. Filter with Label Filters, Contains... `~*` and click on `Grand Total`.  Return to PT, select Does Not Contain... and click on `Grand Total` again.